# .net windows application uses sql server 2005 database…is sql server 2005 required on the client machines

Tags: sql-server

My .net windows application uses sql server 2005 database…is sql server 2005 required on the client machines?
my .net application updates tables in the databases, retrieves data also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a central database server - no, you don't need the full SQL Server on your clients - just the SQL Server client parts.

If you want to run the whole SQL Server 2005 on each machine - then yes, you need SQL Server on each machine in that case. Most likely I'd use SQL Server 2005 **Express** for local work.

It really depends on your scenario - do you **want** to have SQL Server locally on each machine?? Then each user has his/her own database and no data is shared.

Most of the time, you would want to have a single, central SQL Server machine and all the clients connect to it, share and use the same data.